# Testing a Facebook App using localhost

Tags: php, facebook, xampp, localhost

I tried to follow the instructions given in the link http://eugene17.com/2011/03/13/testing-your-facebook-app-in-your-localhost/

I want to be able to test my facebook app locally . It however does not seem to be working . I cant figure out where i am getting it wrong . [image: My app details are this . I have erased certain portions for security. i.e before <code>webapp</code>]

I have also made the following entry in my hosts file .

127.0.0.1       localhost/   -webapp

What wrong have i done ? i am unable to figure it out . This works fine on the live server and one of the machines . However i dont think i can change the app settings to suit my preferences .

More details :

Code which calls the facebook Api :

$facebook_login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => $facebook_app_permissions, 'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri));

The redirect_uri uses get_url() api which resolves to localhost on my system as i am accessing the App by typing /localhost/xxxxx-webapp on my browser ..

Now facebook does not know to connect back to locahost . Hence instead i am redirected to localhost xampp page . There is no error message in the screen nor on the console .

I am trying to get facebook to connect back but i wonder what i am doing wrong . Can somone show me a sample entry in the hosts file ?

The information about the app in facebook is already as shown in the screen shot .

Comment: "http://localhost      -webapp"  Are there actually spaces like that in your URL, or did you white out most of the URL in this screenshot?

Comment: @BryanGentry there are no white spaces . i removed them . It basically localhost/xxxxx-webapp everywhere . i am still unable to get it .

Comment: Can some one please help in answering . I have no leads and things said in other tutorials dont seem to be working ..

Comment: Post more about what you are trying and what is happening. Are you viewing the app at the canvas page URL? Are you browsing Facebook securely? What happens when you try to load the page--Any error messages in Facebook or in your console? Also, it would be helpful for you to post some of the code from the app itself, especially the facebook initialization part of the code.

Comment: Hosts file is used for DOMANIN NAME -> IP ADDRESS translation. You cannot put full URLs like  `127.0.0.1 localhost/XXXXX-webapp` there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is what worked for me . I hope someone stumbles upon it when they are lost .

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/how-to-develop-test-facebook-connect-application-locally/